# PHP Session lost when canceling page refresh on expired page

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I've got a strange behaviour in our website.
I login to our website.
Then I post a form, the form is validated and if an error is recognized the form is shown again with some error information.
Now I do a page refresh (F5), IE asks if I want to refresh (to send the form data again). I confirm this and all is exactly as if I submit the form the first time. No problems, same validation errors...

BUT:
If I cancel the refresh with the cancel button, the page keeps empty and I have to use the back button of IE to navigate to the previous site. Now all session data is lost !!! 
I have to login again.

Does anyone know how to solve this behaviour ?

Greetz
Alex

Comment: It will be good to answer if you post some code..

Comment: plz post your code so we can try to help you

Comment: Sorry, I tried to reproduce the problem in a sample code, but without success. It must be a special behaviour of the current code of our webshop, and that is that large, that I cannot post it all. Any hints where to look ? Has anyone already had the same issue ?